# Not able to write to AWS Glue catalog metastore from spark jobs running on EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aws-glue, amazon-emr

writing a simple spark job running on EMR to create a table stored in Glue catalog but it fails to recognize the glue catalog databases and writing to spark default metastore.

EMR Configurations:-
selected the Use for Spark table metadata check box Under AWS Glue Data Catalog settings .

Spark code :-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object GlueCatalogTableWriter {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Create a SparkSession
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("GlueCatalogTableWriter")
      .getOrCreate()

    // Sample DataFrame
    val data = Seq(
      ("John", 25),
      ("Alice", 30),
      ("Bob", 35)
    )
    val columns = Seq("Name", "Age")
    val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(columns: _*)

    // Write DataFrame to Glue catalog table as Parquet file
    val databaseName = "your_database_name"
    val tableName = "your_table_name"
    val catalogTablePath = "s3://your-bucket/path/to/parquet/file"

    df.write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .format("parquet")
      .option("path", catalogTablePath)
      .saveAsTable(s"$databaseName.$tableName")


    
    // Stop the SparkSession
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

The same code works fine when executing from spark-shell on the master node.

Also tried below option while writing.

```
    .option("fileFormat","hive")
```

Also tried

```
    SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConfWithConfigOpts)
      .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory")
      .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")
      .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Expecting to see table created in Glue Catalog.

Comment: did you get any error message? If that the case please edit your post and add the full message. provide as much [debugging details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as you can

Comment: might be the aws permission problem with glue service